# Trigger lambda function when new recordset added to route53

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-route53

I am looking at ways to trigger a lambda function every time someone add or remove a recordset from the hosted zone. I need to monitor how many recordset are there for every hosted zone. is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS EventBridge to get notified about Route 53 changes, and trigger lambda functions based on these notification events.

There's a similar problem being solved in the knowledge base: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/route53-change-notifications/

Also something on triggering lambda functions via EventBridge: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-cloudwatchevents.html